# How to close Chrome save password pop up in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to close the save password prompt window in Chrome. I am not able to get the control of it.

I tried Xpath, `selenium.webdriver.chrome.options`( by adding arguments)

Also tried

```
alrt = driver.switch_to_alert()
alrt.dismiss()
```

but no luck.

Any help?

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.AddUserProfilePreference("credentials_enable_service", False);
chrome_options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.password_manager_enabled", False);
```

Comment: which chrome options did you try? and do you want to save password, or disable the prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing which worked for me was :

```
chrome_options = Options()
    chromedriver = 'C:\Jars\chromedriver.exe'
    prefs = {"profile.password_manager_enabled": False, "credentials_enable_service": False}
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = chromedriver,chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Answer (score 0):

When defining your WebDriver, set the [AddUserProfilePreference](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Chrome_ChromeOptions_AddUserProfilePreference.htm) Chrome options. Java example:

```
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("credentials_enable_service", false);
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
```

Comment: Provide what you did try in your question. My answer was from [this SQA.StackExchange.com](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/26275/23015) post.